# nvarchar fields in eclipse, crystal reports, sql server 2008

Tags: eclipse, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

Our crystal reports are not developed in eclipse and we are trying to migrate them into eclipse.

When i open an existing report and click on  'verify database' all the nvarchar fields of sql server are not being identified. Eclipse shows a  red x in front of them.

After going through these forums i have not found a solution.

I am using eclipse 3.6.2

Has anyone came across the same issue? Or know of a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of BO/Crystal for Eclipse do you have? This issue is [documented as fixed](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crystalreportsforeclipse/2_0/cr4ev2_readme.pdf) in 2.0 Update 4 (at least, it looks like this issue).

Comment: Yes, some of the forums on sap.com also says it's fixed but i am still facing the issue